# get matched columns data from csv

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, csv

i want to  get selected header data from csv in laravel

my csv is like this

[image]

so if the csv headers is in the below array

```
$Headers=['FIRSTNAME', 'LASTNAME'];
```

, then extract / update their data in csv

i have tried code like

```
$file_n = Storage::path('100Contacts.csv');
$file = fopen($file_n, "r");
$all_data = array();

$i=0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 200, ",")) !== FALSE) 
{
    if($i == 0) //headers
    { 
        for($j = 0; $j < count($data); $j++)
        {
            if (in_array($data[$j], $Headers)) 
            {
                //means header is array
                //?? how to get data based on matching column 
            }
        }
    }

    $i++;
}
```

i was also trying to extract data in seperate array , but after that

```
$all_data[$i]['Prefix'] = $data[0];
$all_data[$i]['FIRSTNAME'] = $data[1];
$i++;

$name = $data[0];
$city = $data[1];
$all_data = $name." ".$city;
array_push($all_data, $arr);
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

This code first reads the line for the headers and then finds which columns are the ones you want to match with....

```
$file = fopen($file_n, "r");
$all_data = array();

$fileHeaders = fgetcsv($file);
$headers=['FIRSTNAME', 'LASTNAME'];
$columns = array_flip(array_intersect($fileHeaders, $headers));
```

At this point `$columns` contains

```
Array
(
    [FIRSTNAME] => 1
    [LASTNAME] => 2
)
```

Which relates to the 2nd and 3rd column (0 based).

Then it reads each row and checks the columns in the data with the record to update, if it matches it just replaces the data (you may need to change this for your needs) and overwrites the data read.  If no match it just copies the data...

```
// Data to be matched and updated
$update = ["Name prefix" => "Mr.", "FIRSTNAME" => "Antonio", 
        "LASTNAME" => "Joy", "Gender" => "M", "EMAIL" => "ccc"];
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 200, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    if ( $data[$columns["FIRSTNAME"]] == $update["FIRSTNAME"] &&
            $data[$columns["LASTNAME"]] == $update["LASTNAME"])      {
        $data = array_values($update);   
    }
    $all_data[] = $data;
}
```

Comment: Has this helped?